# Import and DatelistPlot from CSV

Tags: plotting, import, date-and-time

I have daily time series data on a `CSV` that I'm trying to plot, but I can't seem to make it work nor can I find a clear answer as to what I'm doing wrong.

This is what I have:

This is what my data looks like:

[image]

For code I have:

```
Data = Import["filepath/data.csv", "CSV", "HeaderLines" -> 1 ] // Dataset
```

which seems to work, but then I get an error when I try to use `DateListPlot`.

```
DateListPlot[{Data[All, {1, 2}]}, Data[All, {1, 3}]]
```

I know the issue is something simple that I'm overlooking, but I just can't spot it.

Comment: Could you please post the *.csv file on some place like [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com)?

Comment: perhaps try adding the option `"DateStringFormat" -> {"Month", "Day", "Year"}`  or `"DateStringFormat" -> {"Month", "Day", "YearShort"}` in `Import`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For version 9, you can do the following

```
imp = DeleteCases[Import["C:\\Users\\W10\\Documents\\Book1.csv", "HeaderLines" -> 1, 
    "DateStringFormat" -> {"Month", "Day", "Year"}], "", 2] /. {} ->  Sequence[]
```

> {{{2016, 6, 13}, 1, 2}, {{2016, 6, 14}, 2, 2}, {{2016, 6, 15}, 2,  1},
>    {{2016, 6, 16}, 3, 2}, {{2016, 6, 17}, 2, 2}, {{2016, 6, 18}, 2, 2},
>    {{2016, 6, 19}, 3, 1}, {{2016, 6, 20}, 4, 4}, {{2016, 6, 21}, 4, 4},
>    {{2016, 6, 22}, 6, 6}, {{2016, 6, 23}, 33,  17}, {{2016, 6, 24}, 100, 100},
>    {{2016, 6, 25}, 21, 29}}

And

```
DateListPlot[{imp[[All, {1, 2}]], imp[[All, {1, 3}]]}, Joined -> True ]
```

gives
[image]

In version 11.2, with the free browser version, I can't check if the `Import` command above works, so I copy/pasted the `imp` to the browser.

```
ds = Dataset[imp]
```

[image]

```
DateListPlot[{ds[All, {1,2}],ds[All, {1,3}]}]
```

[image]